# tkinter window without the surrounding

Tags: python, tkinter, window, customization, titlebar

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the borders (titlebar with buttons and the edges on each side) of a tkinter window. Does someone know how to do that?

Couldn't find any solution for this in the web.

Comment: import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+100+100')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.mainloop()

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to `0`

Comment: But a tkinter window has none of those parameters. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: This doesn't remove the decoration around the window. It only works for widgets inside the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley *It only works for widgets inside the window.* -- is not correct, tkinter windows have that option, which you can fairly easy proof by `root.configure(highlightthickness=10, bd=10)`.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: yes, they have that option, but that border appears inside the window edges.